# XMLHttpRequest pending - request to bottle server

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest, bottle

I'm triggering a XMLHttpRequest request using JavaScript (Cf. below) to my bottle server (python) running on an EC2 instance but the request is pending for ages before to get the response.

I have tried the XMLHttpRequest from different IPs, browsers and devices so there is probably nothing to do with that.

From the browser I have copied (Cf. below) the request as a cURL request and when I run it in bash I get a response almost instantly, so I guess that the server is fine.

When the bottle server and the JavaScript script are on the same machine there is no delay either.

I have analysed what was happening on the network between the browser (triggering the request) and the bottle server, the request is sent instantly by the browser but received by the server only later on.
Even if the server gets the request late there are TCP communications between both ends instantly (Cf. tcpdump logs below).

The tcpdump logs are different for cURL and XMLHttpRequest so the way the request is sent must be different which must cause the delay but I can't figure out what it is, any suggestions?

**JavaScript code:**

```js
function httpRequest(url, method, callback)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
        {
            callback(request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open(method, url);
    request.send();
}

function a()
{
}

httpRequest("http://54.194.140.204:8080/initBoard", "POST", a);
```

**Request:**

```
curl 'http://54.194.140.204:8080/initBoard/' -X POST -H 'Origin: http://54.194.140.204' -H 'Referer: http://54.194.140.204/chess_board.html' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36' --compressed
```

**tcpdump logs, when request sent via cURL - successful request:**

```
12:53:37.221682 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [S], seq 1834998039, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294934815 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:53:37.221707 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824: Flags [S.], seq 1990594712, ack 1834998040, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 16676743 ecr 4294934815,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:53:37.249017 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294934822 ecr 16676743], length 0
12:53:37.249052 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [P.], seq 1:306, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294934822 ecr 16676743], length 305
12:53:37.249061 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824: Flags [.], ack 306, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 16676750 ecr 4294934822], length 0
12:53:37.249962 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824: Flags [P.], seq 1:18, ack 306, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 16676750 ecr 4294934822], length 17
12:53:37.250089 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824: Flags [FP.], seq 18:568, ack 306, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 16676750 ecr 4294934822], length 550
12:53:37.273398 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 18, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294934830 ecr 16676750], length 0
12:53:37.278704 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 569, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294934831 ecr 16676750], length 0
12:53:37.278766 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [F.], seq 306, ack 569, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294934831 ecr 16676750], length 0
12:53:37.278779 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.39824: Flags [.], ack 307, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 16676757 ecr 4294934831], length 0
```

**tcpdump logs, when request sent by XMLHttpRequest (part 1) - pending request:**

```
13:03:12.268148 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62360 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [S], seq 2380869158, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
13:03:12.268157 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62360: Flags [S.], seq 2063868765, ack 2380869159, win 26883, options [mss 8961,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:03:12.268161 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62359 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [S], seq 1482241752, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
13:03:12.268163 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62359: Flags [S.], seq 3665352075, ack 1482241753, win 26883, options [mss 8961,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:03:12.294101 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62359 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 1, win 256, length 0
13:03:12.294183 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62360 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 1, win 256, length 0
13:03:13.423863 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [S], seq 2331219208, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
13:03:13.423895 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362: Flags [S.], seq 1304667700, ack 2331219209, win 26883, options [mss 8961,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:03:13.447548 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 1, win 256, length 0
13:03:13.455199 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [P.], seq 1:403, ack 1, win 256, length 402
13:03:13.455216 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362: Flags [.], ack 403, win 219, length 0
```

**tcpdump logs, when request sent by XMLHttpRequest (part 2) - pending request:**

```
13:03:31.399073 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62359 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 256, length 0
13:03:31.399083 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62360 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 256, length 0
13:03:31.399172 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62359: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 211, length 0
13:03:31.399283 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62360: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 211, length 0
13:03:31.400111 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362: Flags [P.], seq 1:18, ack 403, win 219, length 17
13:03:31.400231 IP ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt > cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362: Flags [FP.], seq 18:568, ack 403, win 219, length 550
13:03:31.423809 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 568, win 254, length 0
13:03:31.424063 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62360 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 2, win 256, length 0
13:03:31.424119 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62359 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 2, win 256, length 0
13:03:31.427604 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [.], ack 569, win 254, length 0
13:03:31.432376 IP cpc99924-brnt1-2-0-cust1847.4-2.cable.virginm.net.62362 > ip-172-31-46-188.eu-west-1.compute.internal.http-alt: Flags [R.], seq 403, ack 569, win 0, length 0
```

**cURL headers:**

```
Referer http://54.194.140.204/chess_board.html
Origin http://54.194.140.204
Host 54.194.140.204:8080
Accept */*
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)                                                                                                                                                        Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Length
Content-Type text/plain
Accept-Encoding deflate, gzip
```

**XMLHttpRequest headers:**

```
Referer http://54.194.140.204/chess_board.html
Origin http://54.194.140.204
Host 54.194.140.204:8080
Accept */*
Accept-Language fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)                                                                                                                                                        Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 0
Content-Type text/plain
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
```

Comment: Are the request headers the same for the requests from the two different clients?

Comment: I have added the headers for both clients in the original post, 'Accept-Language', 'Content-Length' and 'Connection' are different